# Calculating time worked per day

Tags: google-sheets

How do I add time like 8:20am-12:00pm and then after lunch break 12:30pm-5:02pm to end of day to get hours worked per day? I was using `=(B2-A2*24)+(D2-A2*24)` but that doesn't work

Comment: Is that to be read as two timespans (`8:20-12:00` and `12:30-05:02`), _or_ as four different periods (`8hrs 20min`, `12hrs 0min`, `12hrs 30min`, `5hrs 2min`)? What is the expected result of your formula?

Comment: I see a couple of issues here. Why are you multiplying by 24? Your 5:02 should be 17:02 unless you're including a "PM" in there. This all assumes that these are times and not durations, as Vidar has asked about. Please [edit] your question to be more specific so we might offer some concrete help.

Comment: Why don't you use this example made on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45039/29140

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've got some order of operations trouble. I think this will give you what you want:

```
=((B2-A2)*24)+((D2-C2)*24)
```

Of course, you also need to ensure that the cell uses a decimal number format. And that your afternoon values need to be actual afternoon values. You need to use 24-hour format or am/pm format.

In any event, using your values above, this formula, and appropriate formatting, this is what I get:

```
 8:20 | 12:00 | 12:30 | 17:02 | 8.20
```

Comment: I have changed the format to time AM/PM and this is how I have the spreadsheet set up A1 8:20 AM B1 12:00 PM C 12:30 PM D1 5:02 PM and formatted the E cell to decimal and used your formula and I get -3.80 for an answer?  What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe Google Spreadsheets is assuming different days? What do you see if you format the cells to show date as well as time?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, concerning your working hours, should be:

`8 hours and 12 minutes ==> 8:12`.

as per time notation.

If you use the following data:

```
 8:20 am | 12:00 pm | 12:30 pm | 5:02 pm |
```

and use the following formula

```
=((B1-A1)+(D1-C1))*24
```

then the result would be 8.2. This is not a time notation !!

If you convert it to a 24h notation (menu Format)

```
 8:20 | 12:00 | 12:30 | 17:02 |
```

and use the following formula

```
=(B2-A2)+(D2-C2)
```

then the result would be 8:12.